# Pairwise measurable derivatives imply measurability of combined derivative

Tags: measure-theory

I've found the following simple claim in an article. Unfortunately, i don't understand the proof given there nor can i come up with an alternative proof of my own. Maybe math.stackexchange can give me a hand?

*Claim* ([HAL], a combination of Lemma 9 and Corollary 3) Let $S=\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A}\right)$ be a measurable space and let $\mathfrak{M}=\left\{\mu_0,\mu_1,\mu_2\right\}$ be a set of three finite measures on $S$. Suppose $\mathcal{T}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$ such that for any two measures $\mu,\nu\in\mathfrak{M}$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu}{d\left(\mu+\nu\right)}$ is $\mathcal{T}/\mathfrak{B}$-measurable. Then $\frac{d\mu_0}{d\left(\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2\right)}$ is $\mathcal{T}/\mathfrak{B}$-measurable.

As an alternative to help in proving the claim, i'd appreciate help in understanding the proof given in the article that i reproduce below almost verbatim. The points that baffle me are:

1. Why is $(*)$ true?
2. In the last paragraph, why would $f$ need to be redefined?
3. In the last paragraph, why is $f$ redefined on a set of $\mu_0$-measure $0$? Shouldn't it be redefined on a set of $\left(\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_3\right)$-measure $0$, since $f$ is unique up to a set of $\left(\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_3\right)$-measure $0$?
4. Why is the redefined $f$ $\mathcal{T}/\mathfrak{B}$-measurable?

*Proof*
Define

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f_1 & := & \frac{d\mu_0}{d\left(\mu_0+\mu_1\right)} \\
f_2 & := & \frac{d\mu_0}{d\left(\mu_0+\mu_2\right)}
\end{array}
$$

Since $d\mu_0=f_1d\left(\mu_0+\mu_1\right)=f_2d\left(\mu_0+\mu_2\right)$, we have $f_1d\mu_0=f_1f_2d\left(\mu_0+\mu_2\right)$ and $f_2d\mu_0=f_1f_2d\left(\mu_0+\mu_1\right)$, so that

$$\left(f_1+f_2-f_1f_2\right)d\mu_0=f_1f_2d\left(\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2\right) \tag{*}$$

If we define

$$f:=\frac{d\mu_0}{d\left(\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2\right)}$$

then it follows that

$$\left(f_1+f_2+f_1f_2\right)f=f_1f_2\space\left[\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2\right]-\mathrm{a.e.}$$

Since $0\leq f_1\leq1$ and $0\leq f_2\leq1$, the equation $f_1+f_2+f_1f_2=0$ is equivalent to $f_1=f_2=0$. Since $\mu_0\left(\left\{x:f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0\right\}\right)=0$, it follows that $f$ may be redefined, if necessary, to be $0$ on the set $\left\{x:f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0\right\}$ without affecting the relation $d\mu_0=fd\left(\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2\right)$; since outside this set $f=f_1f_2/\left(f_1+f_2-f_1f_2\right)$, the proof is complete.

#### References

[HAL] Halmos, Paul R., Savage, L. J. "Application of the Radon-Nikodym Theorem to the Theory of Sufficient Statistics". Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 20, 225-241 (1949)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer some of these points, but from your question I can't see what $\cal{B}$ is, so I'm afraid I've got no answer for your last question.  In order then:

(*) holds because your measures are finite and because of the relationships defined:
$$f_1d\mu_0 = f_1f_2d(\mu_0 + \mu_2)$$ and $$f_2d\mu_0 = f_1f_2d(\mu_0+ \mu_1)$$ so adding these together gives:
$$(f_1+f_2)d\mu_0= 2f_1f_2d\mu_0 + f_1f_2\mu_2 + f_1f_2\mu_1$$ and so:
$$(f_1 + f_2 - f_1f_2)d\mu_0 = f_1f_2d(\mu_0 + \mu_1 +\mu_2)$$

For your second question and third questions, the aim is to be able to divide by the $(f_1 + f_2 -f_1f_2)$ term. So because we know that $(f_1+f_2-f_1f_2) = 0$ iff $f_1 = 0 = f_2$ (with respect to the $d\mu_0$ measure) we may have to redefine $f$ to be zero on that set of points (so that we're not trying to divide by 0)

For your third question look back at (*): $(f_1+f_2-f_1f_2)$ is measured by $d\mu_0$, not $d(\mu_0 +\mu_1+\mu_2)$.

EDIT: ah, I should have surmised that $\cal B$ was Borel really....
That follows from everything that you're using in this theorem being Borel-measurable: if you have two measurable functions $f$ and $g$ then $f+g$, $f/g$ and $kf$ (for $k$ real) are all measurable functions.  Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are given as Radón-Nikodym derivatives they are certainly measurable, and so $f_1f_2/(f_1 + f_2 -f_1f_2)$ is measurable being a permitted combination of measurable functions.

Comment: $\mathfrak{B}$ is the Borel field on the real line.

Comment: Thanks, postmortes. I can follow the symbolic manipulations you carried out to answer my question #1 and understand why, intuitively, they seem to resolve my question. But when i try to rephrase the manipulations in non-abbreviated form and to justify them rigorously, i find myself in the same cul-de-sac as before. Since "$fd\mu=gd\nu$" is merely an abbreviation for "$f\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=g$", and so i don't understand, for instance, what the expression "$\left(f_1+f_2\right)d\mu_0=2f_1f_2d\mu_0+f_1f_2d\mu_2+f_1f_2d\mu_1$" that you used should stands for.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I see your difficulty.  You're right, $fd\mu = gd\nu$ is equivalent to $f\frac{d\mu}{d\nu} = g$, but it would be better to note that it's also equivalent to $d\mu = \frac{g}{f} d\nu$ which in turn is equivalent to $\mu(E) = \int_E g/f d\nu$ for some measurable set $E$.  So rearranging the expression that's giving you trouble you get: $(f_1 +f_2 - f_1f_2)d\mu_0 = f_1f_2 (d\mu_1 +d\mu_2)$ which is equivalent to $\mu_0(E) = \int_E (f_1f_2)/(f_1 +f_2 -f_1f_2) d(\mu_1 +\mu_2)$.  Does that help?

Comment: It helps, but not quite, because i still don't see how to derive this equation rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following unproven proposition in a book by one of the authors of the article that resolves all my questions and can be seen as a concise proof of the claim that was the focus of my original post. I reproduce it here.

> If $\mu_0$, $\mu_1$, and $\mu_2$ are totally finite measures, and if $d\mu_0=f_1d\left(\mu_0+\mu_1\right)=f_2d\left(\mu_0+\mu_2\right)=fd\left(\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2\right)$, then we have, almost everywhere with respect to $\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2$,
>
> $$
> f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{f_1(x)f_2(x)}{f_1(x)+f_2(x)-f_1(x)f_2(x)} &\mbox{if }f_1(x)f_2(x)\neq0,\\
> 0 &\mbox{if }f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> *[HAL] Note 4 to section 32 "Derivatives of Signed Measures", p. 136*

Consult the thread [An identity involving Radon-Nikodym derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369282/an-identity-involving-radon-nikodym-derivatives) for a rigorous proof.

#### References

[HAL] Halmos, Paul Richard. "Measure Theory". Springer-Verlag, 1974.